# Command 'docker exec -it gridd-alpha grid product create --owner myorg --file product.yaml' returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, django, docker, subprocess, hyperledger

Here I am trying to communicate between 2 docker containers, namely djangoapp and gridd-alpha. Here the command 'docker cp product.yaml gridd-alpha:/' is executing fine from inside django app in djangoapp container, but the next command 'docker exec -it gridd-alpha grid product create --owner myorg --file product.yaml' is throwing a error - Command 'docker exec -it gridd-alpha grid product create --owner myorg --file product.yaml' returned non-zero exit status 1.

```
## views.py ##
import subprocess

cmdCpToContainer = 'docker cp product.yaml gridd-alpha:/'
cmdCreateProduct = 'docker exec -it gridd-alpha grid product create --owner myorg --file product.yaml'

resultCoppied = subprocess.run(cmdCpToContainer, shell=True, capture_output=True, universal_newlines=True, check=True)
print('resultCoppied: ' + str(resultCoppied.stdout))
resultCreatedProduct = subprocess.run(cmdCreateProduct, shell=True,capture_output=True , universal_newlines=True, check=True)
print('resultCreatedProduct: ' + str(resultCreatedProduct.stdout))
```

Here I am communicating through /var/run/docker.sock

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    app:
        container_name: djangoapp
        build: .
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        ports: 
            - 8000:8000
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

networks:
    default:
        name: mongodb_network
```

I have also tried using --user, but it throws the same error.

```
docker exec -it gridd-alpha grid product create --owner myorg --file product.yaml
```

Output

```
## OUTPUT ##


Exception Type:     CalledProcessError
Exception Value:    

Command 'docker exec -it gridd-alpha grid product create --owner myorg --file product.yaml' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Can anyone help me resolve this, and thanks in advance.

Comment: You should redesign your application to use a network interface, maybe HTTP, between containers.  The way you've designed this is incredibly dangerous: a process that can access the Docker socket can very easily root the entire host, and `subprocess.run(shell=True)` invites shell-injection attacks that make this even easier.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for your suggestion, we are in the very beginning stage of this project, and this application is just to check the basic functionalities of Hyperledger Grid. The design and architecture of the application are planned for the next stages of this demo. Can you please help me solve the problem that I have mentioned above?